# How to use MAX function in MySQL with the having clause

Tags: mysql, sql, max, having

I am working with the employees table in SQL and I would like to fetch the data for max count of employees

```
SELECT (COUNT(emp_no)) AS emp_count, dept_no 
FROM
dept_emp
GROUP BY dept_no
HAVING COUNT(emp_no) = (SELECT MAX(COUNT(emp_no)) FROM dept_emp)
ORDER BY emp_count DESC
```

So far this is what I have got but this results in an error saying 'Invalid use of group function'. There is another approach I followed by making a table first and then using the having clause but what would be the correct code in the above approach?

Comment: Which database system are you using? Though to be honest, I'd be surprised if there is any which allows this sub-query.

Comment: Using MySQL workbench

Comment: You're using MySQL, MySQL Workbench is a query tool for MySQL.

Comment: Yep, so anything that I can do that must have the HAVING clause? The question I am trying to answer is 

"Display the department where maximum no of employees is working"

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE dept_emp;   and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS dept_emp; for analysis.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE dept_emp

CREATE TABLE `dept_emp` (
  `emp_no` int NOT NULL,
  `dept_no` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `from_date` date NOT NULL,
  `to_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`,`dept_no`),
  KEY `dept_no` (`dept_no`),
  CONSTRAINT `dept_emp_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_no`) REFERENCES `employees` (`emp_no`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `dept_emp_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`dept_no`) REFERENCES `departments` (`dept_no`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Comment: SHOW TABLE STATUS
dept_emp, InnoDB, 10, Dynamic, 331143, 36, 12075008, 0, 5783552, 4194304, , 2021-10-19 21:47:03, , , utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the having at all. The query as it is without the having will bring you all the departments with the number of employees at each one. The one with the most employees in the first row. If you want only that one you can add limit 1 at the end of the query.

Comment: It's a prerequisite of the question to use the HAVING clause.

Comment: can you write the question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can't not use an aggregation over an aggretation, MAX(COUNT()) is invalid

```sql
SELECT (COUNT(emp_no)) AS emp_count, dept_no 
FROM dept_emp
GROUP BY dept_no
HAVING COUNT(emp_no) = ( 
    SELECT MAX(count_result) FROM (SELECT COUNT(emp_no) as count_result FROM dept_emp) as count_table
)
ORDER BY emp_count DESC
```

Side notes:

1. I think there is a missing WHERE in the subquery as the result will be always the same, as we are getting the MAX of a COUNT to a unfiltered table `dept_emp`
2. I think the MAX(COUNT()) is irrelevant in the subquery, since you can just order by the count and limit by one, for example  `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM foo ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC LIMIT 1`
3. If you can avoid the subqueries, databases are incredible slow understanding subqueries, if you are curious prepend EXPLAIN to the sql statement, and see what mysql does for it

Edit: If you provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` for the tables that are involved in employee counting, I can give you the WHERE that you have to write in the subquery

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE dept_emp CREATE TABLE dept_emp ( emp_no int NOT NULL, dept_no char(4) NOT NULL, from_date date NOT NULL, to_date date NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (emp_no,dept_no), KEY dept_no (dept_no), CONSTRAINT dept_emp_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (emp_no) REFERENCES employees (emp_no) ON DELETE CASCADE, CONSTRAINT dept_emp_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) REFERENCES departments (dept_no) ON DELETE CASCADE ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci